# Calling a Windows .exe from C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to call `tlbExp.exe` from C# using `Process.Start`. I pass the command string as argument, but no matter what flavor of it, I always end up with an error message:

```
The system cannot find the file specified

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
```

If I try to run the command string separately in a command window while debugging, it does what it supposed to happen (tlb generated from a dll). However, I can't get it to work from the code.

```
string tlb;
...
tlb += @"C:\Program files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\tlbExp.exe";
tlb += @""""; tlb += @" """; tlb += outputDllPath;
tlb += @""" /out:"""; tlb += outputTlbPath; tlb += @"""";
Process.Start(tlb);
```

Comment: Another thing that worries me is that I might need to deploy this piece on different machines, different architectures. Is it possible to make that generic ?

Comment: where's your code?? My guess is that "The system cannot find the file specified" :)

Comment: Try putting the path to tlbExp.exe in quotes. Right now the system might be trying to open an exe called `Program` located in `C:\`. Maybe just create an instance of Process and use StartupInfo to configure it.

Comment: Use `ProcessStartInfo`. Put separately exe name and arguments.

Comment: Please review the examples on how to use an instance of [ProcessStartInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Using the 64-bit version of Windows?  Then you'll have trouble starting programs that are stored in c:\program files.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, set the Platform target to AnyCPU.  Writing this code is fairly pointless, your user won't have Tlbexp.exe available without installing the Windows SDK.  Only programmers have it and they prefer using the Visual Studio Command Prompt to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the overload that accepts a `ProcessStartInfo` object:

```
var programPath = @"""C:\Program files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\tlbExp.exe""";
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(programPath);
info.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" /out:\"{1}\"", outputDllPath, outputTlbPath);

Process.Start(info);
```

---

To make it generic, change the first line to this:

```
var programFiles = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
var programPath = string.Format("\"{0}\"", Path.Combine(programFiles, @"Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\tlbExp.exe"));
```

Comment: The generic part doesn't help, the exe is in v7.0 on my machine.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I understood his request for a "generic" way with regards to x86 vs. x64, see his comment to the question.

Comment: Yes the architecture is definitely part of the question. But is there a way to handle different versions of the Windows SDK ?

Comment: I don't think that's easily possible. I didn't find an environment variable pointing to the SDK folder. One possibility would be take the first folder inside "C:\Program files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\" that starts with a "v" and assume it is a SDK folder...

Comment: Prob is we can't assume anything about client machines, not even permissions on Program Files subfolders. So we can't even loop through every folder under * SDK\Windows reliably. Not to mention the selective installs of winsdk.

Comment: @b0rg: Normal configuration of windows allows read access to Program Files and all children. Otherwise it would be impossible to execute the programs installed there...

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth  You're assuming "normal", and we can't do that :)

Comment: @b0rg: Nonsense. If a user can't read program files the computer is useless. You need to make a certain set of assumptions, otherwise you will never be able to write a program.

Comment: I say potato etc. Anyhoo we all agree that tlbexp is standalone win32 executable that can be carried as part of the application package and run from application start folder. I can't chceck "depends" right now, cause I'm sitting on one of those corporate workstations that defies "normal". I'm just sayin.

Comment: @b0rg: I am pretty sure that even on your corporate workstation you are able to see the contents of program files...